# Undeclared identifier on declared object

Tags: delphi

I don't know why I'm getting this error on delphi:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Xml.xmldom, Xml.XMLIntf,
  XMLDoc;


type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    XMLDocument1: TXMLDocument;
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure LeerXML();
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure LeerXML ();
var
 Query : IXMLNode;

begin
  XMLDocument1.FileName := 'Query.xml'; <- RIGHT HERE SAYS "[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(36): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'XMLDocument1'"
end;

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LeerXML();
end;

end.
```

Please if you find anything wrong in the code tell me, it's been a while since I've been stuck in this around the internet.

I don't know what is causing this it is the first time I have used this component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LeerXML routine that you've shown is not a method of your TForm1 class, it is a stand-alone procedure unrelated to it.  The two have no connection as far as the compiler is concerned, that's why it is complaining that XmlDocument1 is an unknown identifier.  The compiler cannot see the connection the way you (erroneously, from a compiler's pov) do.

Looked at another way, your TForm1 class has an XMLDocument1 member, and a LeerXML method.  But that LeerXML method is **not** the one the compiler is complaining about.  I'm not going to explain any more for now, you should sense a penny dropping as you read this ...

Btw, once you've realised what the problem is, you'll probably appreciate that the error you've been seeing is as a result of one of the limitations of Delphi being a single-pass compiler that stops on the first error it encounters.  If it were not (single-pass, stopping on first error) it could do a much more helpful job of identifying what the problem really is.

Comment: i.e. change `procedure LeerXML ();` to `procedure TForm1.LeerXML ();`